# Import jpeg for Pixel Image Manipulation

Tags: c, libjpeg

I'm trying to make a C program that composites two images together, pixel by pixel. To store the image, I defined this struct:

```
struct pixel {
    int r;//red
    int g;//green
    int b;//blue
    int a;//alpha
};
typedef struct pixel pixel;
```

and then created an array of pointers to store each pixel:

```
int pixelcount=1000*1000; //Resolution of Image

pixel** image1pointer=malloc(sizeof(pixel*)*pixelcount);
pixel** image2pointer=malloc(sizeof(pixel*)*pixelcount);
pixel** resultimagepointer=malloc(sizeof(pixel*)*pixelcount);
```

then used a `for` loop to initialise and assign (random) data to each pixel for both images, and blend them for the result image. This seems to work fine, but how would I import an actual JPEG (or other image format) into pixel values that this program can use?

I found a library called `libjpeg` that looks like it might be able to do the trick, but I couldn't find how to use it to accomplish this, and how it would return the pixel values.

**Edit:** In addition to converting an image file into raw data, what is the format of the data that I can use to place it in the struct?

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm also concerned with taking the output of libjpeg and placing it into a struct. That answer also basically just says to use libjpeg without specifying how that worked.

Comment: The answer from Peter Parker is pretty explicit.  Assign your struct from the decoded rgba values shown in the answer.

Comment: @TheInnerParty `libjpeg` is a collection of code tailored to manipulating jpeg images. You are free to write your own (by why?). As for your code above, you allocate a million `pointers-to-pointers` which will do you little good. You need 2 allocations per imageXpointer. `pixel **image1pointer = malloc( sizeof *image1pointer * 1000);` to allocate pointers, and then `image1pointer[i] = malloc( sizeof **image1pointer * 1000);` to allocate the structs.  This will allow access by `image1pointer[i][j].red`, etc..